# Draggable window in java?

Tags: java

I want to create a window in java for desktop, and inside the window to put graphics, what I want is that when I drag a graphic I can take it out in a new window, how do I do it?

Comment: First you need to write some code

Comment: I'm new to java, what I want is to know what components I use.

Comment: `java.swing` is the standard Java GUI library. Check out this [link](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-swing)

Comment: Google for Swing tutorials or JavaFX tutorials

Comment: Sounds like you try to open a large can of worms here. Are you experienced in any other language?

Comment: no, only in java